# Creating empty 3-layer nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

If I want to create a 3-layer nested list like `list = [[[],[]],[[],[]]]`, what's the appropriate way to do this? I saw someone else posted solution for the 2-layer nested list as `lst = [[] for _ in xrange(a)]`. Is there a more generalized way to create this nested list without establishing how many lists are in the third-layer?

Also, is there a way to create unequal number of lists in the third layer? For example: `list = [[[],[]],[]]`, where the `len(list[0])=2` and `len(list[1])=0`

Comment: Your first example works fine

Comment: Is `list = [[[],[]],[[],[]]]` not working for you?

Comment: It was an example. I wanted a more generalized way to create a nested list without establishing how many lists are in the third layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way if you know the lengths of the third layer lists beforehand.

```
>>> length = [1,2,3,4] # indicates the lengths of the third layer lists
>>> res = [ [ [] for i in range(j) ] for j in length ]
>>> res
[[[]], [[], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]
```

Comment: you do not need to use loops, use normal "*" operator, `xrange` should be avoid as is is depreciated in python3

Comment: `*` operator should be avoided. see my comment on Daniel's answer. `xrange` converted to `range`. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Python's arithmetic operators to generate your nested lists (this method is more performant than iterating with nested `for` loops):

```
def listmaker(n, m):
    # n = number of lists in the 3rd layer 
    # m = number of lists in the 2nd layer
    return [[[]] * n] * m 

listmaker(2, 2)
# [[[],[]],[[],[]]]

# you could use the "+" operator to create unequal numbers of lists in the 3rd layer
listmaker(2, 2) + listmaker(1, 1)
# [[[], []], [[], []], [[]]]
```

Comment: This certainly is a very wrong way to do it(at least in Python 2.7). If I do `l = [ [ [] ] * 2] * 2`, and then `l[0][0].append(1)`, then `l` becomes `[[[1], [1]], [[1], [1]]]`, which should clearly not happen.

Comment: Actually, the behavior you describe is correct in Python.  Using operators like `*` in this context creates references to the `[]` objects, which means that when you change one such object (like you did with your  `append()`), you change all of the references to that object.  There are lots of SO questions that deal with this concept, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/.  My answer is still more performant than a nested `for` loop for what the OP appears to want to do, without going down a long rabbit hole re.: the OP's possible intentions.

Comment: Additionally, there are many other possible answers (using `map`, Numpy, etc.).  It all depends on what the OP wants to do.